# How AWS-Cognito and DynamoDB will work for mobile development-iOS-Swift

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

I am trying to use AWS Cognito and AWS DynamoDB for my mobile app have gone through with AWS Documentation also but  as much as I dive into I use to get a new service which is somehow interrelated with another, Please help with what is a right approach I am trying to elaborate a more it might possible I understood the things in wrong way :

So I have two screens one is **sign up** and another is **login**

According to me when user will sign in by putting their credentials I am creating an Identity id and dataset which is succesfully created here is the code foe iOS Swift :

```
 @IBAction func submitButtonAction(sender: UIButton)
 {
    var username = self.inputTfUn.text
    var pass = self.inputPAss.text

    let credentialProvider :AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider
    let syncClient :AWSCognito

    credentialProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: AWSRegionType.USEast1, identityPoolId: "**your idetity id**")

    let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region :AWSRegionType.USEast1, credentialsProvider: credentialProvider)

    AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
    syncClient = AWSCognito.defaultCognito()


    credentialProvider.refresh().continueWithBlock { (task) -> AnyObject! in

    print(credentialProvider.identityId)

    let dataset = syncClient.openOrCreateDataset("UserData")

        dataset.setString(self.inputTfUn.text, forKey: "username")
        dataset.setString(self.inputPAss.text, forKey: "password")

        dataset.synchronize().continueWithBlock({ (task) -> AnyObject! in

            if(task.error == nil){
                print("success")
            }
            return nil
        })


    return nil
    }

}
```

`

on click of **submit**
In AWS cognito:

I have an Identity ID and Dataset in cognito.

Now I AM not sure how It will work to get a user authentication. Do I need to save it to DynamoDB If I have to save it how this will work I mean I tried this also by writing lambda function and many things.. but I think I was not going in right direction or its not the right approach ... Please help if any one is clear with right approach.

I would be using AWS Cognito and AWS Dynamo DB.

Answer (score 2):

What I understand is that you are using Cognito to store credentials(username and password) for your app users. Later you want to authenticate users in your app against this data stored in Cognito Datasets. This is not the right use case to use Cognito and we advise against it.

For user authentication you can use any public login providers such as Amazon, Facebook, Google, Twitter and any OpenID Connect compatible provider. Alternatively you have to authenticate your app users with your own authentication process backed by your backend server and database.

After the user is authenticated, you can then use Cognito for creating unique identities and accessing your secure AWS resources.

This wiki might be helpful if you have your own authentication process and then integrate it with Cognito:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/developer-authenticated-identities/